# angularjs - a href dropdown style clears route

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I'm not sure how to word this question but I'll do my best...

I have a AngularJS Spa page and on the main navigation I have an href dropdown style link. Whenever I click on the dropdown, whatever content is inside of my ng-view disappears. I'm assuming it's because the angular route is detecting the '#' in the href and doesn't know how to handle it. How do I configure the route to disregard the '#' and keep whatever is loaded in the ng-view?

Hopefully that makes sense.

**dropdown**

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Orders <b class="caret"></b></a>
```

**angularjs route**

```
var configFunction = function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/productList', {
        templateUrl: '/productList.html'
    })
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/default.html'
    })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
};
```

Comment: Well, I figured it out as soon as I posted this question...If I remove the '#' from the href for the dropdown, it works as expected. Although, I'm not sure if that will cause any other issues with other browsers.

Comment: that's not a dropdown, that's an `<a>` that has dropdown styling added to it.  It doesn't need an `href` attribute at all.

Comment: @Claies thanks for pointing that out. I'll reword the question/title so it's a little more clear. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspected `#` in the href is what is trying to reroute your application as you clicked on the anchor in the dropdown. All you would need to do it to prevent the default behavior of the anchor, i.e do:

```
 <a href="#" ng-click="$event.preventDefault()" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Orders <b class="caret"></b></a>
```

Or not so better way but a commonly done way is to use javascript pseudo protocol and invoke nothing on href, i.e

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle"...
```

Comment: Thank you! the $event.preventDefault() works quite nicely and is probably a better solution than me just removing the '#'.

Comment: <a href="" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Orders <b class="caret"></b></a>